# How to run a powershell script at active directory login

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I created a group policy in In Group Policy Management Editor, in the navigation pane, expand User Configuration, expand Policies, expand Windows Settings, and then click Scripts (Logon/Logoff). I made a logon script as a ps1 file:

```
copy-item "\\server1\Pictures\background.jpg" -Destination "C:\screensaver\" -Recurse
```

I added that ps1 file in the powershell scripts part of the group policy and set it to run powershell scripts first.

I didn't use any parameters which may be causing the issue?

I need each computer to have that `c:\screensaver\background.jpg` image when they login.

It's the only group policy applied to that OU, all the PCs are Windows 10, and the domain controllers are Windows 2012 r2.

Comment: "*I didn't use any parameters which may be causing the issue?*" - what issue?

Comment: The end result isn't working, meaning the powershell script must not be running, as that file isn't making it there when I login to test, on different machines

Comment: You're asking for help with Group Policy, questions on professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You would be better off asking for help on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion creating a (PowerShell-) logon-script for copying a file is not a great solution and out-of-date nowadays.
Make your life easier and use group-policy-preferences for this task. You don't have to create scripts for that.

Open the Group Policy Management Console, select your policy, open the "Preferences"-Node and select "Files". Create a new element and select the source- and the target (as shown below).

After that reboot the client and the file should get copied without coding.

[image: Screenshot Group Policy Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's two parts to implementing your request. Before doing any of the following, make sure that you can log in as one of the users, and manually perform the steps you want the script to complete (to make sure any user restrictions aren't holding you up). So, make sure you can navigate to the remove image location `\\server1\Pictures\background.jpg`, and copy it to the local folder `C:\screensaver`.

1. *Copying the file to the target machine.* You provided the contents of your PS1 file as `copy-item "\server1\Pictures\background.jpg" -Destination "C:\screensaver\" -Recurse`. I believe you'll want to have two slashes "\\" at the beginning of your `\server1` string, resulting in `"\\server1\Pictures\background.jpg"` (the two slashes make this a valid UNC path). Additionally, you included the `-Recurse` parameter. I don't understand the need for this parameter, based off of the documentation, accessible via the command `Get-Help Copy-Item -Full`.

   ```
   -Recurse [<SwitchParameters>]
       Indicates that this cmdlet performs a recursive copy.
   ```

   I would suggest that you include the `-Force` parameter. If you ever update that image, the next time a user logs on, they'll receive the updated image. Without the `-Force` parameter, the command might not overwrite the existing image on disk. Also, you *shouldn't* need the trailing slash on the `-Destination` parameter. I would suggest the command resemble:

   ```
   Copy-Item "\\server1\Pictures\background.jpg" -Destination "C:\screensaver\" -Force
   ```
2. *Configuring the wallpaper via Group Policy* The first link I found via Google Search **set windows 10 wallpaper via group policy** with anything that looked like useful steps was [some grouppolicy.biz](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/) website. I haven't been able to test them, but the main point being that you'll need to make sure that you're actually telling the computer to use the wallpaper you've copied into place.

If you make sure that you've addressed the above items, then it *should* work for you. There may be some considerations for the first time a user logs in, if the image isn't copied over, then the wallpaper may not display until the second time they log in.